# How to use subquery in WHERE? (AdventureWorks)

Tags: sql, sql-server, count, subquery, adventureworks

What am I doing wrong? I need to make sure my column 'OrderCount' only shows values more than 20. **Please note: I am not allowed to use JOIN in this case.**

```
SELECT FirstName, LastName, (SELECT COUNT(SalesOrderID)
                             FROM SalesOrderHeader
                             WHERE SalesOrderHeader.ContactID = Contact.ContactID) AS OrderCount
FROM Contact
WHERE COUNT(SalesOrderID) = (SELECT COUNT(SalesOrderID)
                             FROM SalesOrderHeader
                             WHERE COUNT(SalesOrderID) > 20
```

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you would need to correlate the subquery in the `where` clause as well - yours count all orders, not those of the concerned customers only.

But a subquery seems simpler:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT c.FirstName, c.LastName, 
        (
            SELECT COUNT(s.SalesOrderID)
            FROM SalesOrderHeader s
            WHERE s.ContactID = c.ContactID
        ) AS OrderCount
    FROM Contact c
) t
where OrderCount > 20
```

> Please note: I am not allowed to use JOIN in this case.

This really is a contrived example. In real life situation, a join with outer aggregation and a `having` clause, or a lateral join, would be more appropriate:

```
SELECT c.FirstName, c.LastName, o.OrderCount
FROM Contact c
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT COUNT(s.SalesOrderID) as OrderCount
    FROM SalesOrderHeader s
    WHERE s.ContactID = c.ContactID
) AS o
where o.OrderCount > 20
```

Comment: Thank you, this makes sense!

Comment: Btw, why do you have 't' on line above 'where OrderCount > 20'?

Comment: @dot-combubble: that's an alias for the derived table that the subquery generates. The SQL standard specifies that every derived table must have an alias (although some databases allow otherwise).

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT FirstName, LastName, (SELECT COUNT(SalesOrderID)
                             FROM SalesOrderHeader
                             WHERE SalesOrderHeader.ContactID = Contact.ContactID) AS OrderCount
FROM   Contact
WHERE  Contact.ContactID in (SELECT 
                              SalesOrderHeader.ContactID
                             FROM SalesOrderHeader
                             Group by 
                              SalesOrderHeader.ContactID
                             Having COUNT(*) > 20
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem here isn't the subquery, it's the aggregate function (the `COUNT` in this case) that's causeing the problem. You can't put an aggregate function that references the tables in the `FROM` in the `WHERE` you would need to reference it in the `HAVING`.

I think you can also condense this right down to not need a subquery:

```sql
SELECT C.FirstName,
       C.LastName
FROM dbo.Contact C
     JOIN dbo.SalesOrderHeader SOH ON C.ContactID = SOH.ContactID
GROUP BY C.FirstName,
         C.LastName
HAVING COUNT(SalesOrderID) > 20;
```

Comment: Good idea, but I am not allowed to use JOIN.

Comment: Can you elaborate? *Why* can't you use a `JOIN`? Using one here would make things far more succinct and easier to understand.

Comment: It's part of the exercise, and I don't have a choice. If this was not an exercise, I would use JOIN too.

Comment: Then I would go with the bottom answer from GMB. But a `CROSS APPLY` is still basically a `JOIN`.